# Php check if array has determined values

Tags: php

```php
$numbers = array('1' => '1', '2' => '2');
```

I have an array of numbers from 1 to 12.

There might be values that are not in the range of 1 to 12. Only numbers from 1 to 12 are permitted.

Is there any way in PHP to accomplish this?

Comment: this "permitted" condition refers to keys or the values of this associative array?

Comment: It refers to the values of the associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you wanna filter(key or value or both). so I wrote this code so you can choose the one you need:

I used this array to test the code:

```
$numbers= array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', "3"=>34, "34" => "7", 5=>8);
```

```
<?php
$numbers= array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', "3"=>34, "34" => "7", 5=>8);

# filter key
function filter_number_keys($input_key)
{
    if(intval($input_key) <= 12 && intval($input_key) >= 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
# filter value
function filter_number_values($input_value, $input_key)
{
    if(intval($input_value) <= 12 && intval($input_value) >= 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
# filter both
function filter_number_both($input_value, $input_key)
{
    if(intval($input_value) <= 12 && intval($input_value) >= 1 
    && intval($input_key) <= 12 && intval($input_key) >= 1 ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
# filter values
echo "Filter values : " . PHP_EOL;
print_r(array_filter($numbers, 'filter_number_values', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
# filter keys
echo "Filter keys : " . PHP_EOL;
print_r(array_filter($numbers, 'filter_number_keys', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
# fitler both
echo "Filter both : " . PHP_EOL;
print_r(array_filter($numbers, 'filter_number_both', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Filter values : 
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [34] => 7
    [5] => 8
)
Filter keys : 
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 34
    [5] => 8
)
Filter both : 
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [5] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) can help -

First check if there are any values which dont fit -

```
$check = array_filter($numbers, function($v) {
    return $v < 1 || $v > 12;
});
// check values present
if (!empty($check)) {
    // show error
}
```